# Move files to a target directory using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read a file(input.txt) containing file names and move the corresponding files present in the input.txt to the target location (d:/target)
(script, input.txt and the files to be moved are all in the same directory)

below is what I have tried

```
require 'fileutils'

target = "D://target/"
file='input.txt'
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
  puts line
  FileUtils.mv(line, target)
end
```

but Im facing below error and I have checked other options but unable to fix it. Any ideas, thanks.

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1329:in `stat': Invalid argument @ rb_file
_s_stat - D://targer/north_af.txt (Errno::EINVAL)
```

input.txt

```
north_af.txt
south_af.txt
midd_cji.txt
fg_poi.txt
and so on....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think every line has extra character "\n" at the end. You need to strip it before.

`FileUtils.mv(line.strip, target)`

Comment: I knew I'm missing something silly, thanks a lot. It was the issue.